# changing text periodically in a span from an array with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a span, eg:

```
<p>Here is a sentence <span id="rotate">this</span> is what changes</p>
```

and I'd like the contents of that span to change every few moments between a list of terms, so the contents might change to be:

```
<span id="rotate">then</span>
<span id="rotate">thus</span>
```

and so on. I'd like the text to fade out and then the new text fade in.

Whats the best way to do this via jquery?

Answer (score 14):

You could do something like this, storing the current index on the element rotating using [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to support it multiple places as well:

```
var terms = ["term 1", "term 2", "term 3"]; //array of terms to rotate

function rotateTerm() {
  var ct = $("#rotate").data("term") || 0;
  $("#rotate").data("term", ct == terms.length -1 ? 0 : ct + 1).text(terms[ct])
              .fadeIn().delay(2000).fadeOut(200, rotateTerm);
}
​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​$(rotateTerm); //start it on document.ready
​
```

This fades the first term in, waits 2 seconds, fades it out, changes the text and repeats....just adjust the values to what you want :)

[Here's a quick demo so you can see it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/VB4QC/)

Comment: Great answer! This works. However, could you perhaps explain what's happening here? I'm curious what does the variable "ct" means?

Comment: @DavidBecerra it's just my shorthand for "current term" - it's not longer simply so the code cleanly fits here without scrolling.

Comment: @NickCraver This is quite old, but I have a similar need, however it is a bit more complex. I need to rotate 2 different strings of text, one says "coming soon" in 4 different languages and the second string says "subscribe to be informed". I need these to fade-in/-out synchronised so that the languages match. I tried defining two vars for the two arrays, changing the id="rotate" to a class and then tried an if statement to load the appropriate var, but it doesn't work. Any ideas? Also, I actually used the concept here http://jsfiddle.net/kMBMp/ but modified for 2 strings