# Changing TWO texts periodically in spans/divs

Tags: jquery, html, delay, fadein

OK, I don't have any problems with reading and testing (works like a charm) the question [changing-text-periodically-in-a-span-from-an-array-with-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771789/changing-text-periodically-in-a-span-from-an-array-with-jquery).
The problem is when I want to change two divs, not just one. It jumps not as 0,1,2,3,4,5, but as 0,2,4 and it is not clear for me why.
Here is a [jsFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/Dv2KV/1/)

If I remove `ct== terms.length -1 ? 0 : ct+ 1` as a second validation, it doesn't help.

So how to make it run 0,1,2,3,4,5?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were running rotateTerm twice - once for each animation completing.  I fixed that and also removed the bit that sets the term data variable on title-content as it's not needed...

http://jsfiddle.net/Dv2KV/2/

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `rotateTerm` twice (once in each fadeOut): http://jsfiddle.net/Dv2KV/4/

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `rotateTerm` twice each time through. You'll need to use separate functions or only call `rotateTerm` once.

Answer (score 1):

Simply because your function "rotateTerm" are called two time (fadeOut callback) !

http://jsfiddle.net/Dv2KV/6/