# Incorporating into a line the periodic changing of text

Tags: javascript, html, css, text, hyperlink

I've not had much luck trying to incorporate [this idea/solution/feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771789/changing-text-periodically-in-a-span-from-an-array-with-jquery) into a link such as:

```
<a href="/" title="index">HOME</a>
```

The text *HOME* would be able to switch between various other words, in an ideal world..

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What did you try, and what went wrong? Are you using jQuery, or another library, or plain JavaScript?

Comment: When do you need that text to change? Periodically? On any fixed interval or event?

Comment: Techfoobar - Periodically, at no particular interval.. Regularly enough to be noticed by page viewers.. Possibly every 2-4 seconds?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/about

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution

```
<a id="link" href="#" title="home">HOME</a>  

var array = [];

array.push("home");
array.push("away");
array.push("there");
array.push("there");
array.push("back");
array.push("moon");
array.push("stars");

var link = document.getElementById("link");
var index = 0;
var length = array.length;
var period = 1000; // miliseconds
var id;

function changeLink() {
    index += 1;
    if (index >= length) {
        index = 0;
    }

    link.textContent = array[index].toUpperCase();
    link.title = array[index];
}

id = setInterval(changeLink, period);
```

on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/x6VmY/)

Comment: <div id="sidelol">
    <div id="blogtitl">{title}</div>
    <div id="linkc">
        <a href="/" title="index">HOME</a>
        ~~Paste here~~
        <a href="/ask" title="ask">ASK</a>
    </div>



^ @Xotic750 - thank you! Should this work if I paste the entirety as such?
(Ignorant question, apologies)

Comment: That depends on where you paste it.

Comment: You can not paste the code from the example above directly (unmodified) into a .html document, serve it from a server and expect a browser to interpret it. You must construct the html document appropriately and also enclose the javascript within script tags. Read a tutorial or two, you can find one at the following: http://www.w3schools.com/html/

Comment: Of course, @Xotic750, just one query - can I set the jsfiddle link you gave as a source in style sheet terms?

Comment: Not programatically as in includeable javascript, but sure as a link, use it as you will.