# JQuery text fade in fade out

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout, cycle

I would like to

- replace word from "." to "first"
- After 1 sec, replace word from "first" to "second"
- After 1 sec, replace word from "second" to "first"
- After 1 sec, replace word from "first" to "second"
- After 1 sec, replace word from "second" to "first"
- repeatedly continue the cycle

However my code does not work as what I expected.
- Instead it appends the another word to previous word.

Could you please suggest how I approach this problem? Thank you.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OyWpQq

```
    <h2 class="quotes"><span class="typeBg"><span class="type">.</span></span> 
<span class="details"><a href="#"><span class="detailsText">.</span></a></span> 
 <span class="CTA"><a href="#"><span class="CTAText">.</span></a></span></h2>

.quotes {height:45px !important;margin-top:-17.5px;margin-bottom:17.5px;border:1px solid #bec0c2;padding:10px 0px;}

.typeBg{height:44px;top:-10px;position:relative;padding:10px 15px;background-color:#004a65;color:white;width:140px;white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow:hidden;display:inline-block;}

.type{display:none;}
.CTA,.details{border:1px solid #bec0c2;padding:10px 2px;top:-11px;position:relative;background-color:white;}    
.CTA{height:41px !important;width:138px;text-align:right;white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow:hidden;display:inline-block;}
.details{height:40px !important; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow:hidden;width:736px;display:inline-block;}  

   showFirst();

   function showFirst() {

     $('<span/>').html("first").appendTo($(".detailsText"));
     $(".detailsText").fadeIn(500).delay(1000).fadeOut(500,showSecond);

   }

   function showSecond() {

     $('<span/>').html("second ").appendTo($(".detailsText"));
     $(".detailsText").fadeIn(500).delay(3000).fadeOut(500);

     showFirst();
   }
```

Comment: it will append because you have append

Comment: are you looking for this..?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17254442/how-to-fade-in-out-multiple-texts-using-css-jquery-like-on-droplr-animated-exam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are appending text rather replacing it. I could figure out a minimal solution to this like below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var counterText = ["First", "Second", "Third"];
    var counter = 0;    
    setInterval(change, 1000);
    function change() {
        $('.detailsText').html(counterText[counter]);
        counter++;
        if(counter >= counterText.length) { 
          counter = 0; 
        }
    }  
})
```

```css
 
.quotes {height:45px !important;margin-top:-17.5px;margin-bottom:17.5px;border:1px solid #bec0c2;padding:10px 0px;}

.typeBg{height:44px;top:-10px;position:relative;padding:10px 15px;background-color:#004a65;color:white;width:140px;white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow:hidden;display:inline-block;}

.type{display:none;}
.CTA,.details{border:1px solid #bec0c2;padding:10px 2px;top:-11px;position:relative;background-color:white;}    
.CTA{height:41px !important;width:138px;text-align:right;white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow:hidden;display:inline-block;}
.details{height:40px !important; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow:hidden;width:736px;display:inline-block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class="quotes"><span class="typeBg"><span class="type">.</span></span> <span class="details"><a href="#"><span class="detailsText">.</span></a></span> <span class="CTA"><a href="#"><span class="CTAText">.</span></a></span></h2>
```

Checkout this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvNZMz

Comment: You're welcome. If that helped you, please be kind accept the answer!

Answer (score 1):

`appendTo` only append html to your existing html, so you always add one word. Use the `html` function to replace your previous word. The second problem is, that you have to set your `showFirst` method as callback of `fadeOut` in your second method (same like in function showFirst with show Second), because the execution of `showFirst` should be **after** doing the fade out. The third, if you do an `fadeIn` with 500 millis and a `fadeOut` with 500 millis, your animation duration is one second (1000 millis) and you don't need more delay.

Modify your code as follow:

```
   showFirst();

   function showFirst() {
     //Replace the hole html
     $('.detailsText').html("first");
     $(".detailsText").fadeIn(500).delay(0).fadeOut(500,showSecond);

   }

   function showSecond() {
     //Replace the hole html
     $('.detailsText').html("second");
     $(".detailsText").fadeIn(500).delay(0).fadeOut(500,showFirst);

   }
```

I hope, that solves your problem.
Here is the codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BopWqg

That code gives 1 second between every text. If you want, the word 1 second in opacity: 1, then you can add more millis to your `delay(1000)`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the function [**.appendTo()**](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).

`"We can create content and insert it into several elements at once"`.It means the content is still there.

You can also see [the demo](http://www.w3school.com.cn/tiy/t.asp?f=jquery_manipulation_appendto), just click the button.