# How can I loop through a jquery array and then output each item (starting at index 0) one at a time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to collect user responses and add them into the answers array. Then I want to display the most recent user input (`answers[0]`) into the `.user-answer div`. I've managed to get that part taken care of but if you see a better way to do it then please show me.

The second part of is that I want to show the items in the array one at a time in the `.dynamic-content h2` slot. I need to loop through the array (starting at answers[0]), pull out each item, show it in the div and then move to the next item and show it in the `div`.

Here's a link to the [CodePen](http://codepen.io/brianhaferkamp/pen/ENKWVo/).

### HTML

```
<div class="answer">
  <h1>Life, Liberty, and </h1>
</div>

<div class="user-answer">
  <h1>_________</h1>
</div>

<input type="text"/>
<input type="submit"/>

<div class="dynamic-content">
  <h1>What is your pursuit of happiness?</h1>
  <h2>Output array items here</h2>
</div>
```

### JavaScript

```
// create an empty array
var answers = []; 

// STORE AND OUTPUT DATA ON SUBMISSION

function handleUserInput() {

  // store user input
  var userInput = $('input[type=text]').val(); 

  // append input value to answers array
  answers.unshift(userInput); 

  // add latest user input into the HTML
  $('.user-answer').html('<h1>' + answers[0] + '</h1>'); 

}

// RUN FUNCTION ON SUBMISSION

$('input[type=submit]').on('click', function() {
  handleUserInput();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the best way but here it goes. This method is like you asked to change the SAME DIV dynamically, so no other items are created, they just "change"

Add this function:

```
function rotateTerm() {
  if(answers.length>0){
  var ct = $("#rotate").data("term") || 0;
  $("#rotate").data("term", ct == answers.length -1 ? 0 : ct + 1).text(answers[ct]).fadeIn().delay(2000).fadeOut(200,function(){
rotateTerm();
  });
 }
}
$(rotateTerm);
```

Then in your submission put:

```
$('input[type=submit]').on('click', function() {
  handleUserInput(); 
  $(rotateTerm);
});
```

working [CodePen](http://codepen.io/dragonclaw/pen/KNMLVq) thanks to Nick Craver's answer in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771789/changing-text-periodically-in-a-span-from-an-array-with-jquery/2772278#2772278).

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. I found a script that would loop through list items but i don't want to continue adding to the HTML making it bulkier for people to download the HTML later.

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't know if you want to do this on server side or in client side, but for server side you need to make it work with a server side scripting language, like **PHP**, or **Perl**. For clent side, you need to cancel the default submit event when user clicks the submit button, else the page will refresh posting the form data.

So, to do this without the page refreshing, first add the event to the `onclick` event and pass it to your `handleUserInput` function like this:

```js
$('input[type=submit]').on('click', function(e) {
  handleUserInput(e);
  rotate();
});
```

then, cancel the event by using `preventDefault` to the event object:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

now, to display the data to `.dynamic-content` and add the answers in `h2` tags, you first need to remove all `h2` elements (because you already have an `h2` element there, or you could also `prepend` if you remove the `h2 Output array items here` tag) and then add all the answers starting from the first one like this:

```
$('.dynamic-content h2').remove();

$.each(answers, function(i, v) {
  $('.dynamic-content').append($('<h2/>').text(v));
});
```

The final code will be something like this:

```
var answers = []; // create an empty array

// STORE DATA ON SUBMISSION
function handleUserInput(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var userInput = $('input[type=text]').val(); // store user input

  answers.unshift(userInput); // append value to answers array

  // $('.user-answer').fadeIn().html('<h1>' + answers[0] + '</h1>').delay( 500 ).fadeOut(); // add user input into the HTML

  $('.user-answer').html('<h1>' + answers[0] + '</h1>'); // add user input into the HTML

  $('.dynamic-content h2').remove();

  $.each(answers, function(i, v) {
    $('.dynamic-content').append($('<h2/>').text(v));
  });

  // $('.answer').html('<h1>' + answers[0] + '</h1>'); 
  // $.each(answers[0 + i], function() {
  //   $('.answer').fadeIn().html('<h1>' + answers + '</h1>').delay( 500 ).fadeOut();
  // });

}

$('input[type=submit]').on('click', function(e) {
  handleUserInput(e);
  rotate();
});
```

http://codepen.io/clytras/pen/zoBXpE

Answer (score 0):

Just change your JS a little bit to this:

```js
    var answers = []; // create an empty array
    
    // STORE DATA ON SUBMISSION
    function handleUserInput() {
      var userInput = $('input[type=text]').val(); 
      $('.user-answer').html('<h1>' + userInput + '</h1>'); 
      answers.push(userInput);
      $('.dynamic-content h2').html(answers + ', ');
    }
    
    $('input[type=submit]').on('click', function() {
      handleUserInput();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="answer">
  <h1>Life, Liberty, and </h1>
</div>

<div class="user-answer">
  <h1>_________</h1>
</div>

<input type="text"/>
<input type="submit"/>

<div class="dynamic-content">
  <h1>What is your pursuit of happiness?</h1>
  <h2>Output array items here</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This changed the top and bottom values but it didn't loop through the items, showing them one at a time. That's what I wanted to do. Instead, it appended the items into one long array, showing them all at the same time. See the accepted answer's Pen to see what I was looking for.